# SQL Server determine if values are monotonous

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression

I got a table with some measurements, containing basically  records. And now, I need to determine, if the values are monotonically increasing from time to time, decreasing or none of the above.

I achieved the desired result using CTE expression (the code is below), but the solution seems quite reduntant to me.

Is there a better way to determine, if the field value sequence is monotone, or not?

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Measurements](
    [ObjectID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [measDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [measValue] [float] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY];

DECLARE
  @ObjectID INT = 1;

with measSet as (
  select  row_number() over(order by measDate ) rownum, measValue, measDate
    from dbo.Measurements M
      where M.measDate > convert( datetime, '2013-10-02 08:13:00', 120)  
           and M.ObjectID = @ObjectID
  ) 
select case when count(b.DiffSign) = 1 then 1 else 0 end as IsMonotone 
  from ( 
   select DiffSign from 
    (
    select MSS.measDate , MSS.measValue, MSS.measValue- MSSD.measValue as Diff, 
    case 
      when MSS.measValue- MSSD.measValue is null then NULL
      when MSS.measValue- MSSD.measValue= 0 then NULL
      when MSS.measValue- MSSD.measValue< 0 
      then -1 
      else 1 
    end as DiffSign
    from measSet MSS
    left join measSet MSSD 
      on MSSD .rownum = MSS.rownum - 1 
      ) a
    where a.DiffSign is not null
    group by a.DiffSign
  ) b
```

Comment: Tips: You might want to look at the `SIGN()` function, e.g. `case Sign( MSS.measValue - MSSD.measValue ) when 0 then ...`. Compare execution plans of various solutions. What looks elegant may not be what the optimizer handles gracefully.

Comment: Thnaks for reminding about the SIGN function - it works fine, but in my case, it is important to exclude "0"-diff values from monotone analysys - they should not cause the result. Otherwise I would use the SIGN func without a doubt.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't care about knowing what particular records are breaking the monotony, then you could use something like this, which is a little more compact:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN COUNT(*) = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS IsMonotone
FROM (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY measDate) AS RowNum, measValue
    FROM Measurements
) T1 INNER JOIN (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY measValue) AS RowNum, measValue
    FROM Measurements
) T2 ON T1.RowNum = T2.RowNum
WHERE T1.measValue <> T2.measValue
```

Comment: That's probably the most elegant solution here